# Use a second ORDER by in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I am using the following query to select the nearest rows to a specified latitude and longitude. The results are then ordered by distance, returning the nearest rows out of the selected data set.

However, I would like to then order the returned nearest rows by the `expiry_date` field to order that data set so that I will have the ending soonest (nearest expiry date) at the top and furthest at the bottom.

Please can you tell me how I can do this?

```
SELECT * , ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( 51.61062 ) ) * COS( RADIANS( - 0.236952 ) - RADIANS( longitude ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( latitude ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( 51.61062 ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM  `questions` 
WHERE  `expiry_date` > 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP HAVING distance <=50000
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (<your query here>) t
order by expiry_date desc
```

Answer (score 35):

`ORDER BY` can be a comma separated list. Just list them by order of presdence:

```
SELECT * , ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( 51.61062 ) ) * COS( RADIANS( - 0.236952 ) - RADIANS( longitude ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( latitude ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( 51.61062 ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM  `questions` 
WHERE  `expiry_date` > 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP HAVING distance <=50000
ORDER BY distance
, expiry_date DESC
LIMIT 0 , 15
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't look like the extra `expiry_date` makes any difference to the end data set.

Comment: This solution does not answer the problem.  It will still only return things by distance, but not sorted by expiry date.

Comment: Can't speak to the OP's problem, but in my situation this works just fine.